# Embed XSL in XML for Display in Web Browser: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: xml, xslt, embed

So I tried to research this and I'm almost at my wits' end. I found a way to embed XSL in XML on [dpawson.co.uk](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/onefile.html),
but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've scoured the internet trying to find solutions and explanations, but no one seems to have an answer.

I'm trying to create one file that is server-independent so I can send one file to my colleagues in hopes that they may view the file by opening it in their web browser.

Here's my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!--Start XSL-->

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="#stylesheet"?>

<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
id ID #REQUIRED>
]>
<doc>

<xsl:stylesheet id="stylesheet"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />
    <!--Variables-->
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="list/movie/seen[@value ='Yes']" />
    <xsl:variable name="b" select="list/movie/seen" />
    <xsl:variable name="c" select="sum(list/movie/rating/@value)" />
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="$c div count($a)" />
    <xsl:variable name="e" select="count($a) div count($b)" />
    <xsl:variable name="f" select="list/movie/seen[@value ='No']" />
    <xsl:variable name="g" select="list/movie/seen[@value ='Prior']" />
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="count($f) div count($b)" />
    <xsl:variable name="j" select="count($g) div count($b)" />
    <xsl:variable name="minutes_total" select="sum(list/movie/length[@value ='y'])" />
    <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="$minutes_total mod 60" />
    <xsl:variable name="hours" select="floor($minutes_total div 60) mod 24" />
    <xsl:variable name="hours2" select="floor($minutes_total div 60)" />
    <xsl:variable name="days" select="floor($hours2 div 24)" />
    <xsl:decimal-format name="percent" />
    <xsl:decimal-format name="average" decimal-separator="." />
    <!--End Variables-->
    <xsl:template match="/doc">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    h2{
                    font-family: Courier, Courier New, monospace;
                    font-size: 32px;
                    text-decoration: underline;
                    }
                    body{
                    font-family: Courier New, monospace;
                    }
                    p{
                    font-size: 16px;
                    }
                    table{
                    font-size: 14px;
                    }
                    .title{
                    text-align:left;
                    }
                    .release{
                    text-align:center;
                    }
                    .seen{
                    text-align:center;
                    }
                    .rating{
                    text-align:right;
                    }
                    .length{
                    text-align:center;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>My Movie List</h2>
                <p>Movies seen so far: <xsl:value-of select="count($a)" />/<xsl:value-of select="count($b)" /> = <xsl:value-of select="format-number($e, '#%', 'percent')" /><br />
                Movies yet to see: <xsl:value-of select="count($f)" />/<xsl:value-of select="count($b)" /> = <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h, '#%', 'percent')" /><br />
                Movies seen prior to making list: <xsl:value-of select="count($g)" />/<xsl:value-of select="count($b)" /> = <xsl:value-of select="format-number($j, '#%', 'percent')" /><br />
                Total time watched: <xsl:value-of select="format-number($days, '#0')" /> days, <xsl:value-of select="format-number($hours, '#0')" /> hours, <xsl:value-of select="format-number($minutes, '#0')" /> minutes<br />
                Average rating:  <xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '#.000', 'average')" /> stars out of 5</p>
                <br />
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Release Date</th>
                        <th>Length</th>
                        <th>Seen</th>
                        <th>Rating</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="list/movie">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test='seen = "Yes"'>
                                <tr style="background-color:#666; color:#fff">
                                    <td> <xsl:number /></td>
                                    <td class="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                                    <td class="release"><xsl:value-of select="release"/></td>
                                    <td class="length"><xsl:value-of select="length" /> minutes</td>
                                    <td class="seen"><xsl:value-of select="seen"/></td>
                                    <td class="rating"><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test='seen = "Seen prior to making list"'>
                                <tr style="background-color:#999; color:#000">
                                    <td> <xsl:number /></td>
                                    <td class="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                                    <td class="release"><xsl:value-of select="release"/></td>
                                    <td class="length"><xsl:value-of select="length"/> minutes</td>
                                    <td class="seen"><xsl:value-of select="seen"/></td>
                                    <td class="rating"><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
                                    <td> <xsl:number /></td>
                                    <td class="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                                    <td class="release"><xsl:value-of select="release"/></td>
                                    <td class="length"><xsl:value-of select="length" /> minutes</td>
                                    <td class="seen"><xsl:value-of select="seen"/></td>
                                    <td class="rating"><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
<!--Start XML-->
 <list>
    <movie>
        <title>2001: A Space Odyssey</title>
        <release>1968</release>
        <seen value="No">No</seen>
        <rating>N/A</rating>
        <length value="n">141</length>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>28 Days Later</title>
        <release>2002</release>
        <seen value="No">No</seen>
        <rating>N/A</rating>
        <length value="n">113</length>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>28 Weeks Later</title>
        <release>2007</release>
        <seen value="No">No</seen>
        <rating>N/A</rating>
        <length value="n">100</length>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>A Clockwork Orange</title>
        <release>1971</release>
        <seen value="Yes">Yes</seen>
        <rating value="2">&#9734;&#9734;&#9734;&#9733;&#9733;</rating>
        <length value="y">136</length>
    </movie>
<!--Rest of XML-->
</list>
</doc>
```

It's a list of movies that contains how many I've seen so far, how many I've yet to see, how many I've seen before I made the list, the total amount of time I've put into watching movies, and the average rating per movie seen.

The problem is the that all the variables are showing up with zero value, which causes divide by zeros which give NaN value on some of the output as well.

Anything anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do here but I don't think that this is a stylesheet. Your <xsl:stylesheet> tag is embedded within a <doc> tag which is very strange

Comment: Unfortunately, my XML was too large to fit entirely in the body of the question. What I'm trying to do is get my variables to work. When I have the .xml and .xsl files separate, it works beautifully. But when I embed, the xml shows up, but my variables don't work. I get a lot of 0s and NaNs.

Comment: What are you doing with this document. You say "the xml shows up". Where? What software are you running, and how?

Comment: I'm trying to embed the xsl into the xml doc. I'm viewing the xml doc with Safari, editing it with Komodo. When I say the xml shows up, I mean that the data stored in the xml is displayed. However, my problem is with my variables. The variables don't seem to act the way they ought to.

Comment: @SamuelPearseWalters: Turns out it was a simple XPath problem; see my answer below for the solution.

Comment: I don't see anything different between the two code listings. In the answer you wrote "adds /doc before /list". Did you really mean /list before /doc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The following code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#stylesheet"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
id ID #REQUIRED>
]>
<doc>
 <!--Start XSL-->
 <xsl:stylesheet id="stylesheet"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />

   <!--Variables-->
   <xsl:variable name="a" select="/doc/list/movie/seen[@value ='Yes']" />
   <xsl:variable name="b" select="/doc/list/movie/seen" />
   <xsl:variable name="c" select="sum(/doc/list/movie/rating/@value)" />
   <xsl:variable name="d" select="$c div count($a)" />
   <xsl:variable name="e" select="count($a) div count($b)" />
   <xsl:variable name="f" select="/doc/list/movie/seen[@value ='No']" />
   <xsl:variable name="g" select="/doc/list/movie/seen[@value ='Prior']" />
   <xsl:variable name="h" select="count($f) div count($b)" />
   <xsl:variable name="j" select="count($g) div count($b)" />
   <xsl:variable name="minutes_total" select="sum(/doc/list/movie/length[@value ='y'])" />
   <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="$minutes_total mod 60" />
   <xsl:variable name="hours" select="floor($minutes_total div 60) mod 24" />
   <xsl:variable name="hours2" select="floor($minutes_total div 60)" />
   <xsl:variable name="days" select="floor($hours2 div 24)" />
   <!--End Variables-->

  <xsl:decimal-format name="percent" />
  <xsl:decimal-format name="average" decimal-separator="." />

  <xsl:template match="/doc">
   <html>
    <head>
     <style>
      h2{
      font-family: Courier, Courier New, monospace;
      font-size: 32px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      }
      body{
      font-family: Courier New, monospace;
      }
      p{
      font-size: 16px;
      }
      table{
      font-size: 14px;
      }
      .title{
      text-align:left;
      }
      .release{
      text-align:center;
      }
      .seen{
      text-align:center;
      }
      .rating{
      text-align:right;
      }
      .length{
      text-align:center;
      }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h2>My Movie List</h2>
     <p>Movies seen so far: <xsl:value-of select="count($a)" />/<xsl:value-of select="count($b)" /> = <xsl:value-of select="format-number($e, '#%', 'percent')" /><br />
     Movies yet to see: <xsl:value-of select="count($f)" />/<xsl:value-of select="count($b)" /> = <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h, '#%', 'percent')" /><br />
     Movies seen prior to making list: <xsl:value-of select="count($g)" />/<xsl:value-of select="count($b)" /> = <xsl:value-of select="format-number($j, '#%', 'percent')" /><br />
     Total time watched: <xsl:value-of select="format-number($days, '#0')" /> days, <xsl:value-of select="format-number($hours, '#0')" /> hours, <xsl:value-of select="format-number($minutes, '#0')" /> minutes<br />
     Average rating:  <xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '#.000', 'average')" /> stars out of 5</p>
     <br />
     <table border="1">
      <tr>
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Title</th>
       <th>Release Date</th>
       <th>Length</th>
       <th>Seen</th>
       <th>Rating</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="list/movie">
       <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='seen = "Yes"'>
         <tr style="background-color:#666; color:#fff">
          <td> <xsl:number /></td>
          <td class="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td class="release"><xsl:value-of select="release"/></td>
          <td class="length"><xsl:value-of select="length" /> minutes</td>
          <td class="seen"><xsl:value-of select="seen"/></td>
          <td class="rating"><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
         </tr>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test='seen = "Seen prior to making list"'>
         <tr style="background-color:#999; color:#000">
          <td> <xsl:number /></td>
          <td class="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td class="release"><xsl:value-of select="release"/></td>
          <td class="length"><xsl:value-of select="length"/> minutes</td>
          <td class="seen"><xsl:value-of select="seen"/></td>
          <td class="rating"><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
         </tr>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
         <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
          <td> <xsl:number /></td>
          <td class="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td class="release"><xsl:value-of select="release"/></td>
          <td class="length"><xsl:value-of select="length" /> minutes</td>
          <td class="seen"><xsl:value-of select="seen"/></td>
          <td class="rating"><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
         </tr>
        </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
    </body>
   </html>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>

 <!--Start XML-->
 <list>
  <movie>
   <title>2001: A Space Odyssey</title>
   <release>1968</release>
   <seen value="No">No</seen>
   <rating>N/A</rating>
   <length value="n">141</length>
  </movie>
  <movie>
   <title>28 Days Later</title>
   <release>2002</release>
   <seen value="No">No</seen>
   <rating>N/A</rating>
   <length value="n">113</length>
  </movie>
  <movie>
   <title>28 Weeks Later</title>
   <release>2007</release>
   <seen value="No">No</seen>
   <rating>N/A</rating>
   <length value="n">100</length>
  </movie>
  <movie>
   <title>A Clockwork Orange</title>
   <release>1971</release>
   <seen value="Yes">Yes</seen>
   <rating value="2">&#9734;&#9734;&#9734;&#9733;&#9733;</rating>
   <length value="y">136</length>
  </movie>
  <!--Rest of XML-->
 </list>
</doc>
```

**Produces the desired output as shown below when saved as an XML file and opened in the FireFox web browser.** Formatting is not displayed here, but will be when you open an XML file containing the above code in FireFox.

```
My Movie List

Movies seen so far: 1/4 = 25%  
Movies yet to see: 3/4 = 75%  
Movies seen prior to making list: 0/4 = 0%  
Total time watched: 0 days, 2 hours, 16 minutes  
Average rating: 2.000 stars out of 5  

# Title         Release Date    Length      Seen    Rating  
1 2001: A Space Odyssey 1968    141 minutes No      N/A  
2 28 Days Later         2002    113 minutes No      N/A  
3 28 Weeks Later        2007    100 minutes No      N/A  
4 A Clockwork Orange    1971    136 minutes Yes     ☆☆☆★★
```

**Note 1: The problem was the change of element nesting level caused by embedding the XML** `<list>` **within the** `<doc>` **element when you put the XML and XSL into the single file format.** The solution adds `/doc` before `/list` in all of your XPath expressions in order to select the desired elements which are now nested one level deeper as descendants of `<doc>` *and* `<list>` instead of just descendants of `<list>` (like they were when the two files were separate).

**Note 2: xml-stylesheet type was also changed to "text/xsl" as a step towards compatibility with IE 8.** With the "text/xml" type, IE 8 just displays the document tree (including XSL) as XML, while with "text/xsl" it attempts--albeit rather unsuccessfully--to apply the transformation. More work would be required to make this display correctly in IE 8. Note that either type value works fine in FireFox 7. No other browsers were tested.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was totally lost with this problem, but your solution helped a lot. Thank you, Witman!

Comment: Quick update: Solution works fine on Chrome 29 and Firefox 23. Didn't work on IE10 (in case anybody wants to know)