# Embedding complex XSL into complex XML (CDA)

Tags: xml, xslt, hit, cda

I'm trying to embed [this XSL](https://github.com/chb/sample_ccdas/blob/master/CDA.xsl) into a [CDA Document](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC130066/).  This particular document begins something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <realmCode code="US"/>
    <typeId .../>
    ...
    <recordTarget>
        <patientRole>
        ...
```

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523174/embed-xsl-in-xml-for-display-in-web-browser-what-am-i-doing-wrong) I have tried a couple things, including pasting the XSL within the `<ClinicalDocument>` element and creating a new root element that contained both the `<ClinicalDocument>` and the `<xsl:stylesheet>`.  Neither of these worked.  From doing some research it looks like I need to modify the XSL to exclude itself perhaps?  I haven't had any luck doing this, or modifying the XSL at all as I'm not that familiar with the technology and it's test patterns.

**Update** [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31188865/736893) is working in Chrome but I'm getting this in IE:

[image]

Comment: Depending on exactly what you are trying to accomplish, it might be better to do the transform yourself, and then just distribute the resulting HTML file.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option :(

Comment: Show us what you did and we can tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed an `xsl:stylesheet` and reference it using `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#sheetId"?>` then you need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#mySheet"?>
<!DOCTYPE ClinicalDocument [
<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
  id    ID  #REQUIRED>
]>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <xsl:stylesheet id="mySheet" ...>...</xsl:stylesheet>
    <realmCode code="US"/>
    <typeId .../>
    ...
    <recordTarget>
        <patientRole>
    ...
</ClinicalDocument>
```

The stylesheet is too long for me to check all code but at least the first templates don't make use of any generic path like `*` which could result in processing the stylesheet elements themselves so the above might suffice.

Comment: Chrome just shows a blank page and IE throws `XSLT8690: XSLT processing failed.`  Ideas?

Comment: Okay, yeah Chrome does work but IE throws that same error.  I tried with a different XSLT and had the same results.

Comment: I updated the original question with the full IE console output.

Comment: I tried a simple test case http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015062601.xml with IE 11 and it seems it does not apply the XSLT and indeed gives that error you have named. I don't know whether IE ever supported that `href="#id"` notation, sorry. Mozilla and Chrome seem to support it, I don't know what do to about IE.

Comment: Big sigh.  I'll keep looking.  I doubt all our customers use Chrome/FF

Comment: Does this mean anything to you? http://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/201108/msg00120.html